# Closure of set with certain attributes

Tags: general-topology

I am having a hard time solving the following problem:

Suppose we have a nonempty set $E$ $\subseteq$ $(0,\infty)$ with the following attributes:

1) If $x\in E$ then $x/2\in E$

2) If $x , y \in E$ then $\sqrt {x^2+y^2} \in E$.

We have to prove that $\operatorname{cl}(E)=[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @skyking I thought there was something wrong with my claim as well . So I came in contact with my professor and found there was a missing part in my claim . I have now added the missing part and it makes sense now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use two observations. Suppose $a\in E$ (exists since $E$ is non-empty), then property (1) means that $a2^{-n}\in E$ for any positive integer $n$. And property (2) implies that $ka\in E$ for any positive integer $k$. In combination this means that $ka2^{-n}\in E$ for any positive integers $k$ and $n$.

What $\operatorname{cl}(E) = [0,\infty)$ means is that for any $c\in[0,\infty)$ there exists a sequence $c_n\in E$ such that $\lim c_n = c$.

We can construct this as $c_n = k_na2^{-n}$ where $k_n$ is the smallest integer such that $c < k_na2^{-n}$ (since $c\ge0$ this guarantees that $k_n>0$ and since it's the smallest it guarantees that $0<c_n-c\le 2^{-n}$).

Comment: I made the same observations , but had a hard time constructing the sequence . It never crossed my mind to request k to be the smallest integer . Very nice , thank you .